# Carregar Campos através do DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Estou com um dropdownlist (cbreceitas) que é carregado através do SqlDataSource, onde após carregado o de cbreceitas, ele carrega o cbplanos através do SqlDataSouce, segue o código:

```html
<div class="grid-9">
  <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Receita"></asp:Label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="cbReceitas" runat="server" class="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlReceitas" DataTextField="descricao" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbReceitas_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlReceitas" runat="server" SelectCommand="select id, descricao from plano_contas where tipo = 'R' order by [descricao] asc" OnInit="SqlReceitas_Init" OnLoad="SqlReceitas_Load"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
<div class="grid-9">
  <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Planos"></asp:Label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="cbPlanos" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlPlanos" DataTextField="descricao" DataValueField="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbPlanos_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control" OnDataBinding="cbPlanos_DataBinding"
    OnLoad="cbPlanos_Load" OnTextChanged="cbPlanos_TextChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlPlanos" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [descricao] FROM [servicos] WHERE ([plano_id] = @plano_id) order by [descricao] asc" OnInit="SqlPlanos_Init" OnLoad="SqlPlanos_Load">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cbReceitas" Name="plano_id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Quando carrega o cbReceitas, que automaticamente carrega o cbPlanos, eu preciso que faça algumas alterações no textbox, com este código:

```js
Nome_Pessoa();
Valor_serviço();
txtHistorico_desta.InnerText = cbReceitas.SelectedItem + "(" + cbPlanos.SelectedItem + ")" + " - " + aluno_nome;
```

Só que ele só funciona se eu clico em cbplanos e mudo. O primeiro plano que carrega não altera os textbox, em todos os eventos que eu coloco não dá certo, apenas se eu clicar e mudar do segundo e voltar para o primeiro. Em qual evento eu posso fazer, para que carregue junto com os SqlDataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

marianac_costa,

Você pode fazer essa alteração no ItemDataBound do grid.

```
   void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) 
   {
      if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
      {
           txtHistorico_desta.InnerText = cbReceitas.SelectedItem + "(" + cbPlanos.SelectedItem + ")" + " - " + aluno_nome;
      }
   }
```

Acredito que algo nesse sentido funcione.

Comment: Vou fazer o teste e volto para informar o que ocorreu.

Comment: Você realizou os testes?